# Redirect (stderr of redirect) to stdout

Tags: c, sh, popen

The title is slightly confusing, because this might be an XY problem.

I am aware that `2&>1` will redirect the stderr of a program to stdout.

Here's my problem. I'm trying to do this:

`popen("echo Y > /sys/class/.../somefile.txt", "r")`

And detect if the command fails. I know if the command fails from the CLI if I see the following on stderr:

`-sh: echo: write error: Device or resource busy`

However, I can't seem to capture this output no matter what I try.

If I do  `popen("echo Y > /sys/class/.../somefile.txt 2&>1", "r")` it simply redirects the original echo statement's stderr to stdout, not the stderr of the redirect operation. In that case, how can I detect if the command has failed? I also tried examining the return code of `pclose` but that doesn't seem to change either (always `0`).

Comment: So basically you try to check whether it's possible to write `Y` to `/sys/class/.../somefile.txt`? If so, then it'd be much easier to just open that file with `fopen` and check if `fopen` fails or not.

Comment: @yeputons Sorry, I forgot to mention that this is not a normal file. It's a virtual driver file and fopen/ofstream always fails to open it even though the echo does not fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Order of redirections is significant. As you've written it, the order is:

1. Redirect stdout to `somefile.txt`.
2. Redirect stderr to whatever stdout is now.

What you want is:

1. Redirect stderr to the original stdout.
2. Redirect stdout to `somefile.txt`.

So use:

```
popen("cmd 2>&1 >somefile.txt", "r")
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize order mattered

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure if this answers what you want, but you can use `&>` to redirect both stdout and stderr to something